# What’s the difference between “ambient” and “ambiente”

Tags: vocabulario

In Spanish, what’s the difference between “ambient” and “ambiente”. Both mean “ambiences”, but when would you use one over the other? Please explain making reference to the below.

**Example 1:**

> **tiene un buen ambients y está decorado bien** 
>   *It has a great atmosphere
>   and it is decorated well.*

**Example 2:**

> **la casa tiene un ambiente muy desagradable**
>   *The house has a very unpleasant atmosphere*

Comment: This is surely a typo. Note that *ambiente* means a lot of things, like "ambience", "atmosphere" and "environment".

Comment: In Catalan, ambients is the plural of ambient....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word ambient does not occur in the official dictionary of the RAE so i suspect this is a typo. The letters e and s are quite close at least on my keyboard. There is the further clue that the first example states *un buen ambients* implying that it is singular which conflicts with the s being a plural.

Comment: Would the correct version be:  `tiene un buen ambiente y está decorado bien ` Thanks!

Comment: @big_smile that sounds better.